# How to remote access Aster express through ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, remote-access, ping

I am using latest version of Aster express edition form Teradata and configured, which is run only in windows so create a virtual machine of windows on my Ubuntu machine, and its perfectly working in SUSE (using Aster Client Tools - ACT) and windows 7 (Teradata studio).

But I want to use that aster express edition with my UBUNTU(on which window m/c virtually configured , in which my aster express edition is installed) but And when i ping form SUSE to windows and windows to Ubuntu and viceversa,its working but when i ping form Ubuntu to SUSE is shows unreachable.

So my requirement is that i want to access Aster express edition in Ubuntu or remotely in other machine .... Any body HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

so you created a Windows VM on your Ubuntu machine, installed VMware player for Windows, and then installed Aster Express in the player, right?

You could try using VMware Player for Linux directly on your Ubuntu machine.  It's not officially supported, but it seems to work.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes it is working fine in Linux directly.